# WordPress filter to hook into menu <li> items and add a custom attribute

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, hook, wordpress

I have a WordPress template I'm trying to build and I can't seem to figure out how to hook into the menu that WordPress outputs and add a custom attribute to that menu's `<li>` tags. The current menu outputs like this:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu-1" class="top-bar-menu right">
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="menu-item "><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#work">My Work</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

(Those links are just there for sample)

I need WordPress to automatically add the following attribute to the `<li>` tags: `data-magellan-arrival="[target]"`.

`[Target]` needs to automatically be populated by the page_ID that the menu item corresponds to. So for example, let's say that first's `<li><a href="">[PAGE]</a></li>` link is Home and Home's page_ID is "21" (example). I would need `data-magellan-arrival="[target]"` inside of `<li>` to be set to `data-magellan-arrival="21"`.

So it would look like: `<li class="menu-item" data-magellan-arrival="21"><a href="">[PAGE]</a></li>`

I'll be honest with you, I'm not that great at PHP just yet and WordPress filters/hooks much less. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction or show me how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//add to functions.php
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'magellanlinkfilter');
function magellanlinkfilter($val)
{
    $postid = url_to_postid( $val['href'] );
    $val['data-magellan-arrival'] = $postid;
    return $val;
}
```

Here's the complete list of hooks: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks